# Send push notification to my flutter app from backend

Tags: .net, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to send notifications to users of my Flutter app programmatically. I want my backend to handle this task because it needs to retrieve data from the database to personalize the notifications.

In my research, I've come across Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) and OneSignal as potential solutions. However, I'm unsure how to integrate either of these services with my .NET backend to send notifications.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: For FCM did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#c?